# Is there a Postgres time interval formatter to show age as 3y, 4mo, 2w, 6d, 7h, 55m, 24s, now and so on?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-formatting, date-formatting, postgres-9.6

Is there a Postgres time interval formatter to show age as `3y, 4mo, 2w, 6d, 7h, 55m, 24s, now and so on`? Similar to how Reddit shows the age of a post/comment?

My data type for the timestamp column is as follows:

`api_created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()`

I am able to get the age of this timestamp from `now()` using:

`select age(now(),api_created_at) from post;`

This gives `2019-09-04 10:04:19.882688+01` as :

```
2 days 23:36:45.27627
```

I need this age as a more friendlier string similar to reddit. Is there a built in formatter for this? Or a custom function I can use?

**EDIT:** I need it to make it 'rounded off' / floor / ceil? Like how reddit simply says "3d" instead of "3d 23m 55s". So instead of lets say 1d 2h, it simply says 1d.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `to_char()` for this:

```sql
select to_char(age(timestamp '2019-09-07 10:53:14', timestamp '2019-09-04 10:04:19'), 
               'yy"y" mm"mo" dd"d" mm"m" ss"s"')
```

returns

```
00y 00mo 03d 00m 55s
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it 'rounded off' / floor / ceil? Like how reddit simply says "3d" instead of "3d 23m 55s". So instead of lets say 1d 2h, it simply says 1d.  Sorry, in my question, I meant it to be specific.

Comment: @PranoyC: nothing built-in. You would need to write your own function using `extract()` on the interval elements and concatenating the string you want

Comment: Okay, thank you! I looked at the extract() function and I have an idea on how to do it.